Why read channel with go fmt.Println(<-c) doesnt work?
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go fmt.Println(<-c)
    c <- 32
}


I have a goroutine that is blocked waiting for a value to a channel and have a write to a channel in the main goroutine. Why is the deadlock happening?
It seems to me that everything should be working, but a deadlock is occurring

The issue here is that the argument to fmt.Println is evaluated before the new goroutine is started up, not after. See the page on A Tour of Go. In other words, the code you have is (mostly) equivalent to doing the following:
val := <-c
go fmt.Println(val)

This causes the main thread to deadlock because it is waiting for c to produce a value to pass into fmt.Println on the main goroutine. Since this keeps the goroutine busy, it never reaches the later line where you actually send a value on the channel.
Try this instead:
go func() { fmt.Println(<-c) }()

Here, the execution of the function is handed off to a separate goroutine before <-c is evaluated. This allows the main goroutine to continue down until it hits c <- 32 to provide a value for the channel.

You created blocking channel (without buffer). It is used to accomplish a "rendezvous", so both sender and receiver will be ready to exchange data.
Goroutine parameters are evaluated during goroutine creation, meaning that your code will try to read from channel before starting new thread.
One solution:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }()
    c <- 32
}


Go is trying to read the value for your goroutine before creating the goroutine.
It's the equivalent to:
go func(i int) {
  for.Println(i)
}(<-c)

To have the block inside the goroutine, you should read the channel inside the goroutine instead of reading it as an arg for the goroutine.
go func()
  fmt.Println(<-c)
}

This way, you first invoke your goroutine and then read the channel.

On another note, I don't know if the result of the program is random depending if the routine is killed before the print can be called.
